# I have a problem with installing

Tags: 14.04

```
root@ubuntu:~# yum install nfs.utils
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu doesn't use `yum` - that utility is for RPMs and Red-Hat based distros.

Ubuntu is based off of **Debian** which uses `.deb` packages.  You need to use `apt` or `apt-get` to install things.

With regards to NFS utils, you can install them with `apt install nfs-utils`.